# how to convert swift code into objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I want to convert below code in objective c,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, 
                 continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, 
                 restorationHandler: (([AnyObject]!) -&gt; Void)) 
                 -&gt; Bool {

  let userInfo = userActivity.userInfo as NSDictionary
  println("Received a payload via handoff: \(userInfo)")
  return true
}
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = userActivity.userInfo;
    NSLog(@"Received a payload via handoff: %@", userInfo);
    return YES;
}
```

Like this?

Comment: The only tricky part is the `restorationHandler`, but it is not even used, so ...